# How to create a login screen which don't include App.vue components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am creating a SPA which have a login screen and other views. But the problem I am facing is, the login screen view also includes in the Navigation bar but It should not be there. Then I used Router navigation which displays a navigation bar alone without any views I think it also guards the Login view also.

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <section id="app" class="hero">
    <section class="main-content columns is-fullheight has-background-white-bis">
      <Navigation />
      <div class="hero-body">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</template>

<style>
.menu {
  margin: 25px;
}
</style>

<script>
import Navigation from "@/components/Navigation.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Navigation
  }
};
</script>
```

> router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
        path: '/LoginUser',
        name: 'login',
        component: LoginUser,
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
    },
}]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

var isAuthenticated = false;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) next('/LoginUser')
    else next()
})

export default router
```

[image: I am getting this when isAuthenticated is false]
[image: I am getting this when isAuthenticated is true]

Comment: Add a v-if to the navigation bar container, which listens to a variable which is true on the parent component when logged in

Comment: Yes it is correct. I added the same which given by @Djip. It works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the navigation when specifically on the Login route, you can add a `v-if` to your `<Navigation />` component, which checks if the route is not on the login page:

```
<Navigation v-if="this.$router.currentRoute.name !== 'login'" />
```

Answer (score 3):

We can conditionally render components by checking the name of the current route using v-if directive. I used this in a recent project.

My route index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: Register
  }  
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

My App.vue file

```
<template>
    <div id="app">

/* Note that this takes an array of route names, so you can simple pass in
the name of the route you dont want this component to be displayed on */

        <navbar v-if="!['login', 'register', 'help'].includes($route.name)" />
    
        <main>
            <router-view />
        </main>
    
        <appfooter v-if="!['login', 'register'].includes($route.name)"/>
    
    </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Nice way. tks a lot